# How to implement multiplication between class instances and float and class instance in Python

Tags: python, class

I am trying to write a class that simulates a complex number in Python. Yes, I know there already exists a built-in function called `complex()` which can be used to construct a complex number, and we can also use `j` to create them. However I wanted to write my own just for fun. Here is a small version of it:

```
class Complex:

    def __init__(self, real: float = 0, img: float = 0):
        self.real = real
        self.img = img
        self.num = (self.real, self.img)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        string = "{real}".format(real=self.real) if self.real != 0 else ""
        # Want to have "a + bi", "a", "bi"
        # Want to avoid "+ bi" or "a + "
        if self.real != 0 and self.img < 0:
            string += " - "  # img will already have -
        elif self.real != 0 and self.img > 0:
            string += " + "
        string += "{img}i".format(img=abs(self.img)) if self.img != 0 else ""
        return string

    def __add__(self, other: 'Complex') -> 'Complex':
        return Complex(self.real + other.real, self.img + other.img)

    def __sub__(self, other: 'Complex') -> 'Complex':
        return Complex(self.real - other.real, self.img - other.img)

    def __matmul__(self, other: 'Complex') -> 'Complex':
        # (ac - bd)
        real = self.real * other.real - self.img * other.img
        # (ad + bc)
        img = self.real * other.img + self.img * other.real
        return Complex(real, img)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Complex(self.real * other, self.img * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__mul__(other)
```

The issue is that I cannot find a way of defining the following:

- Complex * Complex (left multiplication for class instances)
- Complex * Complex (right multiplication for class instances, but useless as the above will suffice)
- float * Complex (right scalar multiplication, but can be with int as well)
- Complex * float (left scalar multiplication, but can be with int as well)

This is because when I multiply two class instances, it still calls `__mul__` while it does not call `__matmul__`. I think `__matmul__` should only work with `@` operator. How can I make all of this work without having to use another operator (`@`) ? I would like to use the standard `*` operator.

Comment: Why did you implement `__matmul__`?

Comment: Because I thought that would have worked with instance * instance as well for some reason. The thing is I don't want to check whether "other" in `__mul__` is of type `Complex` or of type `int` or `float`

Comment: "The thing is I don't want to check whether "other" in `__mul__` is of type `Complex` or of type `int` or `float`" - just check already. It's the standard approach, and essentially mandatory.

Comment: Okay I will. I thought it was bad practise to sort of "overload" a method like this in Python. Do you know then how I could adjust the type hints that I am providing?

Comment: So for instance, would I write `def __mul__(self, other: 'Complex') -> 'Complex':` or would I write `def __mul__(self, other: int) ->int:` or `def __mul__(self, other: float) -> float:` ?

Comment: You shouldn't even have those type hints - methods like `__add__` or `__mul__` are supposed to take arbitrary types and return `NotImplemented` if they don't recognize how to handle the argument.

Comment: That makes more sense! Thank you! Do you know where I could find more information about these kind of good practices / bad practices?

Comment: (There are tools you can use like [`functools.singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) you can use to perform the type checking for you, although you'd need to delegate to a helper and put `singledispatch` on the helper because it has to dispatch on the first argument. You could also have your instances support the `real/imag` attributes and use `real/imag` for all handled types, but you'll still need some sort of check to determine whether to return `NotImplemented`.)

Comment: Your `__repr__` should be `__str__`; the string returned by `__repr__` should, to the extent possible, return a string that could be used to recreate the instance. In this case, something like `return "Complex({}, {})".format(self.real, self.imag)`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you have to test for type and execute the proper arithmetic based on type.

```
class Complex:

    def __init__(self, real: float = 0, img: float = 0):
        self.real = real
        self.img = img
        self.num = (self.real, self.img)

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        string = "{real}".format(real=self.real) if self.real != 0 else ""
        # Want to have "a + bi", "a", "bi"
        # Want to avoid "+ bi" or "a + "
        if self.real != 0 and self.img < 0:
            string += " - "  # img will already have -
        elif self.real != 0 and self.img > 0:
            string += " + "
        string += "{img}i".format(img=abs(self.img)) if self.img != 0 else ""
        return string

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Complex):
            return Complex(self.real + other.real, self.img + other.img)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return Complex(self.real + other, self.img)
        
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self + other

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Complex):
            return Complex(self.real - other.real, self.img - other.img)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return Complex(self.real - other, self.img)
        
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return -self + other
    
    def __neg__(self):
        return Complex(-self.real, -self.img)
    
    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Complex):
            real = self.real * other.real - self.img * other.img   # (ac - bd)
            img = self.real * other.img + self.img * other.real    # (ad + bc)
            return Complex(real, img)
        elif isinstance(other, int) or isinstance(other, float):
            return Complex(self.real * other, self.img * other)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self * other
```

and a few tests:

```
a, b = Complex(1, 2), Complex(2, 1)
a + 2, 2 + a, a - 2, 2 - a, 2 * a, a * 2, a + b, b + a, a - b, b - a, a * b, b * a
```

output:

```
(3 + 2i,
 3 + 2i,
 -1 + 2i,
 1 - 2i,
 2 + 4i,
 2 + 4i,
 3 + 3i,
 3 + 3i,
 -1 + 1i,
 1 - 1i,
 5i,
 5i)
```

In the same vein, you can implement `__iadd__` (`+=`), `__isub__` (`-=`), `__imul__` (*=), paying attention to mutate the argument instead of returning a new object.